# Експорт класса в node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

Мне нужно експортировать класс Room, но пишет что нет такого конструктора:

Room.js

```js
class Room
{
    constructor () 
    {
        this.name = "";
        this.password = "";
    }
}

exports.Room = Room;
```

index.js

```js
var Room = require("./classes/Room")
var r = new Room();
```

---

Выбивает ошибку,

> Room is not constructor

Comment: Room = require(...).Room;

Comment: @AlexeyTen спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Room.js

```
class Room
{
    constructor () 
    {
        this.name = "";
        this.password = "";
    }
}
module.exports = Room;
```